# Javascript array containts element

Tags: javascript, arrays, contains

I'm new in javascript and i have a question.
i have an array of element, i want to test if the array containts a specified element then update it if not add a new element.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < datasourcedatas.length; i++) {
     alert(item.id+" itemid "+ datasourcedatas[i].id);

     if(item.id==datasourcedatas[i].id){
        alert(item.id+" itemid "+ datasourcedatas[i].id+"  boucle");
        datasourcedatas[i].produitqan=qan;
        item.produitqan=qan;
        break;
     } 
     else {
             cartDataSource.add(item);
     }    
 }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the question is asking why the item gets added repeatedly.

The reason is that you're adding it on **every iteration of the loop** if that iteration's entry doesn't match.

Instead, you need to determine whether the entry is in the array using the loop, then only add it if not *afterward*, when done looping.

```
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < datasourcedatas.length; i++) {
    if (item.id == datasourcedatas[i].id) {
        found = true;
        datasourcedatas[i].produitqan = qan;
        item.produitqan = qan;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    cartDataSource.add(item);
}
```

Technically, you don't need the `found` variable, you could use `i`:

```
// I don't like or suggest this, just pointing it out
for (var i = 0; i < datasourcedatas.length; i++) {
    if (item.id == datasourcedatas[i].id) {
        datasourcedatas[i].produitqan = qan;
        item.produitqan = qan;
        break;
    }
}
if (i >= datasourcedatas.length) {
    cartDataSource.add(item);
}
```

---

Note that `ES2015` added `Array#find`, which is useful for this and can be shimmed/polyfilled:

```
var found = datasourcedatas.find(function(entry) {
    return item.id == entry.id;
});
if (found) {
    found.produitqan = qan;
    item.produitqan = qan;
} else {
    cartDataSource.add(item);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot i will try it